# Entity Framwork Code First: How to load associated objects from within an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Say you have two classes, order and customer:

```
public class Customer{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order{
    public int OrderId{get; set;}
    public Customer OrderCustomer{get; set;}
}
```

Now, I would like to add a "CanBeDeleted" method to my Customer class that tells my program if this customer can be deleted. I want to make sure that a customer can only be deleted if no orders exist:

```
public class Customer{
       public int CustomerId { get; set; }
       public string CustomerName { get; set; }
       public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

       [NotMapped]
       public bool CanBeDeleted {
           get {
               return Orders.Count() == 0;
           }
       }
   }
```

Of course, the problem is, that the program doesn't know if the Customer was loaded with the include option for orders.

How can I make sure from within the "CanBeDeleted" getter that the orders are loaded / how can I load them without having a reference to the DbContext?

Comment: Could you make the assumption that `CustomerId` would be zero (default) if the `Customer` object is not attached?

Comment: @DamM: If the customer is not attached, `Order.OrderCustomer` is null (unless this is a new customer that has never been saved to the database, in which case by convention Customer.CustomerId will be 0).

Comment: @Eric-J, ahh true. I've gotten into the habit of initializing collections in the constructor so I don't have to check for null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Entity Framework Code First will lazy load related entities when they are accessed.

However, your properties that hold the related entities must be declared `virtual`, which you don't seem to be doing.

The reason they must be declared `virtual` is that Entity Framework creates a proxy class that overrides your implementation and injects the code to load the related entities upon first access.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx